# javascript typeerror while reading 3d array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

i have the following 3d array. i want to parse the 1st element of each array element, which should return all the dates.

```
    var res = [[["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:38:49 GMT",0,"ams1"],["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:43:49 GMT",2,"ams1"],["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:48:49 GMT",8,"ams1"]],[["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:53:49 GMT",2,"ams1"],["Mon, 23 Nov 2020 10:58:49 GMT",5,"ams1"]]]
console.log(res);
var data1=[]
for (var i=0; i<res.length; i++)
{
    for (var j=0;j<res[i].length;j++);
    {
        data1.push(res[i][j][0]);
    }
}
```

This gives a type error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

any help please.

Comment: It's a typo, remove the semicolon at the end of `for..j`.

Answer (score 0):

you have added an extra `;` which is causing the error in this line: `for (var j=0;j<res[i].length;j++);`. remove it and it should work.

Comment: i literally banged my head for 3 hours missing this.  thanks a lot.